# Do I have to use "Synchronized block" for thread safety?

Tags: session, thread-safety

```
CsrfValidationInterceptor.java

String sessionToken = CSRFTokenManager.getTokenForSession(request.getSession());

CSRFTokenManager.java

public static String getTokenForSession (HttpSession session) {
    String token = null;
    synchronized (session) {
        token = (String) session.getAttribute(CSRF_TOKEN_FOR_SESSION_ATTR_NAME);
        if (null==token) {
            token=UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            System.out.println("TOKEN: "+token);
            session.setAttribute(CSRF_TOKEN_FOR_SESSION_ATTR_NAME, token);
        }
    }
    return token;
}
```

If I delete synchronized (session) {}, is it not thread safe? I don't know why? Please explain a detailed scenario.